# Why can't I convert a two-dimensional array to a two-dimensional pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why does the following program give a `'conversion' : cannot convert from int[1][1] to int**` error? I am compiling with VS2008 under Windows 7.

```
int main(){
    int a[1][1] = {0};
    int **p = a;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  **Arrays are not pointers**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only convert arrays to pointers one time. The "pointers == arrays" abstraction breaks from the second level onwards.

You can do

```
int (*p)[1] = a; //convert an array of arrays of length 1
                 // to a pointer to arrays of length 1
```

But it becomes clear you cannot convert multidimentional arrays to pointers-to-pointers if you see the memory layout in each case:

```
//multidimentional arrays (a[][])
a -> [first row][second row][...]

//pointers to pointers (**p)
p -> [p0][p1][p2]
      |    |   |
      |    |   \-> [third row]
      |    \-----> [second row]
      \----------> [first row]
```

In the pointer-to-pointer approach the rows are not necessarily contiguous and there needs to be an extra array for the spine that points to the individual rows.

Comment: I thought,arrays were always continuous..?

Comment: You *can* continuously allocate the data from the second case if you really want to but there will be no way to get rid of that additional array to store the pointers to the lines.

Answer (score 4):

`a` is an array of an array of `int`s, so it can decay to a pointer to the first element, which is an array of `int`s. So you need to declare the pointer as follows:

```
int (*p)[1] = a;
```

More abstractly, if you have an array `T a[N];`, then `a` decays to a `T*`. In your situation, you have `T = int[M]`, and so `T* = int(*)[M]`.

Comment: This was actually a more useful explanation for me, after I had already tried casting to `int *[M]` (which turns out to be a row of pointers, instead of a pointer to a row).  The contiguity problem is intuitive, unlike operator precedence.