# passing a pointer to a pointer in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Compiling:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


void f(int ** v)
{
}

int main()
{
    int v[2][3];
    f(v);
    return 0;
}
```

failed with:

```
g.cpp:13:8: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void f(int**)’
```

But the following changes passed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


void f(int ** v)
{
}

int main()
{
    int * v[2];
    f(v);
    return 0;
}
```

It seemed to me that the deeper dimensions of an array has to be solved upon compilation, and can somebody elaborate more about it?

Comment: The former is not a pointer to a pointer, it's a 2D array (which will decay to a pointer to an array). Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing multidimensional arrays as function arguments in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051/passing-multidimensional-arrays-as-function-arguments-in-c), or [Why can't I convert a two-dimensional array to a two-dimensional pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264392/why-cant-i-convert-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-two-dimensional-pointer-in-c), or many others.

Comment: [My compiler complained when I passed a two-dimensional array to a function expecting a pointer to a pointer.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html) And why this C tagged question has a C++ example?

Comment: @effeffe because, correct me if I'm wrong, the OP does not have a clue what the hell he is doing. Is it safe to retag the question as C++?

Comment: @Andreas Grapentin Source code editted to remove the C++ features. Please use the right words!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ automatically coerce arrays to pointers.  The error is caused due to the fact that this coercion happens only once (i.e. at only the first level).  This means `int [10]` will get coerced to `int *`; but `int [10][10]` can at most get coerced to an `int *[10]`.

The reason has to do with memory layout.  You see, `a[i]` translates to `*(a + sizeof(T) * i)` if `a` is of the type `T *` (assume adding to pointers directly adds without scaling); but if `a` is of the type `T [N]`, `a[i]` translates to `*(&a[0] + i)`.  Thus, it follows that a value of type `T [N]` can be coerced into a value of type `T *` by taking the address of the first element -- the memory layouts are compatible in this case.

However, a two dimensional array `a` (of type `T [2] [4]`, say) will be stored differently than a double pointer (of type `T **`).  In the first case, you have the four elements,`T [0][0]` to `T [0][3]` laid out in memory followed by `T [1][0]` to `T [1][3]` and so on, modulo alignment.  In the second case, you just have a bunch of pointers (to `T`) laid out one after the other.  In the first case, `a[i][j]` will get lowered into `*(&a[0][0] + sizeof(T) * 4 * i + sizeof(T) * j)` while in the second case it will get lowered into `*(*(a + sizeof(T) * i) + sizeof(T) * j)`.  The memory layouts are no longer compatible.

Comment: Great answer! Explanations on the memory layout is exactly what I am looking for! Just make sure it's a typo. Should a[i][j] be lowered to *(*(a + sizeof(*T) * i) + sizeof(T) * j) instead of *(*(a + sizeof(T) * i) + sizeof(T) * j)?

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to an int is something different than a pointer to an array.

When doing `v++`, the compiler must be informed, if to increment the address by `sizeof(int)` or by `array_length*sizeof(int)`