# Passing a pointer to a pointer in a procedure in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, procedure

I'm trying to pass a pointer to a pointer to a procedure, but i get a segfault everytime, while passing it to a function works perfectly fine.
I guess it may have something to do with the coercion C does automatically on arrays to pointers, such as in this question : 
[passing a pointer to a pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264950/passing-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-in-c) .

But i don't know how to fix it.

Here's the code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void creer_matrice(int nbCol, int nbLigne, char **matrice)
{
     int i,j;

     matrice = calloc( nbCol, sizeof(char*));

     if( matrice == NULL ){

         printf("Allocation impossible");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

     }

     for( i = 0 ; i < nbLigne ; i++ ){

          matrice[i] = calloc (nbCol, sizeof(char*));

            if( matrice[i] == NULL ){

             printf("Allocation impossible");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

             }
      }


      /* Remplissage de test*/
     for(i = 0; i < nbLigne; i++){

           for(j = 0; j < nbCol; j++){
             matrice[i][j] = 'I';
           }

     }

   //return matrice;
}


int main(){
    int i,j;

    char **matrice;

    creer_matrice(8,6,matrice);

    //matrice = creer_matrice(8,6);

      for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
         for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            printf("%c ",matrice[i][j]);
         }
      printf("\n");
      }

}
```

Can somebody please tell me where i am wrong and how to solve it ?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: You might want to write your code with english variables and comments.

Comment: Note: there is no distinction between "function" and "procedure" in C...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JMkPpg26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this lines:

```
 for( i = 0 ; i < nbLigne ; i++ ){

      matrice[i] = calloc (nbCol, sizeof(char*));
```

To:

```
 for( i = 0 ; i < nbCol ; i++ ){

      matrice[i] = calloc (nbLinge, sizeof(char));
```

Or event better: allocate memory for whole matrix in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrice = calloc( nbCol, sizeof(char*));
```

Here you're not allocating enough memory for your matrix. You need to allocate the memory depending on the size of your matrix and the type you store in it:

```
matrice = calloc(nbCol * nbLigne, sizeof(int));
```

And remove

```
matrice[i] = calloc (nbCol, sizeof(char*));
```

Try to do as less system calls as possible. If you can allocate all matrix in a single call, do it. You already know the exact size to be allocated at the start of your function.

And don't forget to free your allocated memory once you're finished.

```
free(matrice);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I forgot to change the allocation.

Comment: I also thought about allocating in one line, but the problem is, i need to access it as a matrix (such as matrice[i][j]).

Comment: Doesn't matter, one allocation is enough. I suggest you check a good C tutorial.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you think there's an error in the argument i'm passing to the procedure ?

Comment: No, it's ok, but don't forget to free the memory when you're done (see my answer edit).